# How to activate python virtual environment by shell script

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, virtualenv

I wrote a shell script as.

```
    source ve/bin/activate
```

Saved it as activate_shell.sh latter when I ran the script with command.

```
    bash activate_shell.sh
```

The script is being run with no error but the virtual environment is not being activated.

Comment: If so? `./activate_shell.sh` , before `chmod +x activate_shell.sh`

Comment: I tried that first but it was giving error command not found

Comment: the "error command not found" probably means that the executable bit wasn't set. run `chmod +x activate_shell.sh` to set that

Comment: Maybe error in the script?

Comment: I did tried that but result was that the script executed without error but virtual environment was not activated. I also tried sh activate_shell.sh error was source: not found

Comment: Got the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13122317/992665 thanks for flagging the question anyway.

Comment: Shell is not bash, so it's not strictly a duplicate. Source doesnt exists in shell. so accepted answer is not actually useful. I would say either repoen or tagging with bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your activation script path, `ve/bin/activate`, is relative. The script will only work from one directory. But the problem is not here.

What does `bin/activate` do? It modifies the shell *in which it runs*. This is why you have to `source` it and not invoke as a regular program.

The script you wrote starts its own copy of shell (bash), activates the virtual environment inside it, and exits, destroying the just-activated environment. If your script invoked Python after sourcing the `bin/activate`, it would be the Python from the virtual environment, not the system one.

If you want a simple, easy-to-type command to activate a virtualenv, define a *shell function:*

```
ve() { source $1/bin/activate; }
```

(Yes, type the above line right into your shell prompt.)

Then type `ve foo` and virtualenv named `foo` will be activated in your current shell, provided that you're in the right directory.

Should you need to cope with a massive amount of virtualenvs, take a look at   [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper).

Comment: Is there a way to make the ve() function stick between shell sessions?

Comment: @gcr: Define it in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. whichever exists.

Answer (score 5):

Using a script to run `source` command defeats its purpose as `bash activate_shell.sh` will create another shell.  All modification by the `active` command would modify the newly created shell, which terminate upon completion of your `activate_shell.sh` script.

A easy way to do this is to add alias to your `.bash_profile` instead:

```
alias activate_shell="source ve/bin/activate"
```