# Installing python packages in a virtual environment via bash script and pip

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, virtualenv

To clarify I have read these questions already:

[How to source virtualenv activate in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122137/how-to-source-virtualenv-activate-in-a-bash-script)

[How to activate python virtual environment by shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391943/how-to-activate-python-virtual-environment-by-shell-script?lq=1)

[Activating virtualenv in Bash script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235469/activating-virtualenv-in-bash-script-not-working?rq=1)

[Bash: How _best_ to include other scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192292/bash-how-best-to-include-other-scripts)

My goal is to create a script that will automate the process of installing several (roughly 27) python packages via pip in  a virtual environment using (preferably) a bash script.

So far in bash scripts I have tried:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install numpy Scipy ez_setup
```

As well as

```
activate() {
. ../.env/bin/activate
}

activate
pip install numpy Scipy ez_setup
```

Neither of which works. What is the best way to approach this problem given it must be executable as part of a larger bash (or python) script?

Comment: `source env/bin/activate` should work - is there any output? The name of the venv should appear in brackets prepended to your terminal prompt.
It's possible you may have to execute `scl enable python27 bash` if you are in a remote environment.

Comment: In this case I'm actually not working in a remote environment, but yes this is what I had expected too, yet it doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: So I figured out my problem. The solution for me is to force the script to pull from the correct pip directory with

```
/env/bin/pip install numpy Scipy ez_setup
```

The second part is to break down the install instructions into each line because the registries were not being updated properly.